# Change values in a masked np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an np array of arrays:

```
arr = np.array(
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],
[11,12,13,14,15,16],
[21,22,23,24,25,26],
[31,32,33,34,35,36],
[41,42,43,44,45,46]])
```

and a mask that selects 'rows' from `arr`

```
mask = np.array([False,True,True,True,True])
```

I am trying to change values in the original array by giving relative indices to the masked array:

```
arr[mask1][0,0] = 999
```

expected output:

```
[[  1   2   3   4   5   6]
 [999  12  13  14  15  16]
 [ 21  22  23  24  25  26]
 [ 31  32  33  34  35  36]
 [ 41  42  43  44  45  46]]
```

However, the problem is that `arr` remains unchanged. Any workaround suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's Happening: Fancy vs Regular Indexing

This happens because using a boolean array or a sequence of indices is "fancy" indexing.  ("Fancy" is anything that can't be expressed as a slice.)  It's not actually a "masked array" which is a separate thing entirely in numpy terminology (`np.ma.masked_array`).

Fancy indexing makes a copy.  Regular indexing (i.e. slicing) makes a view.  Views share data, copies do not.

Let's break down your expression `arr[mask1][0,0] = 999`.

Because `mask1` is a boolean array, `arr[mask1]` will return a copy of the data.  The next part will modify that copy, rather than the original array. In other words:

```
# tmp_copy is a copy, not a view, in this case
tmp_copy = arr[mask1]

# tmp_copy is modified, but `arr` is not
tmp_copy[0, 0] = 999 

# Because `tmp_copy` is an intermediate, it will be garbage collected.
# The assignment to 999 effectively disappears
del temp_copy
```

Let's contrast that with a similar (in this exact case) slicing expression: `arr[1:][0, 0] = 999` (which would modify the original `arr`)

```
# Because we're using a slice, a view will be created instead of a copy
tmp_view = arr[1:]

# Modifying the view will modify the original array as well
tmp_view[0, 0] = 999

# The view can be deleted, but the original has still been modified
del tmp_view
```

---

### How Can I Work Around This?

Generally speaking, you'd avoid putting yourself in this situation.  What you're wanting to accomplish can usually be re-cast another way.

However, if you really need to, you can do it by translating the fancying indexing into specific indices that you want to modify.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

# Your data...
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                [11,12,13,14,15,16],
                [21,22,23,24,25,26],
                [31,32,33,34,35,36],
                [41,42,43,44,45,46]])
mask = np.array([False,True,True,True,True])

# Make a temporary array of the "flat" indices of arr
idx = np.arange(arr.size).reshape(arr.shape)

# Now use this to make your assignment:
arr.flat[idx[mask][0, 0]] = 999
```

In your exact case this is overkill (i.e., you could do the same with `arr[1:][0, 0] = 999`).  There are plenty of other cases where things can be simplified.  However, to get a fully general solution, we need something similar to the example above.

### Explaining the Workaround

Let's break down what that example does.  First we create an array of "flat" indices of the same shape as our array. (Side note, see `np.unravel_index` for more information.) In this case:

```
In [37]: idx
Out[37]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

Now we can extract the indices that the fancy indexing would extract:

```
In [38]: idx[mask]
Out[38]:
array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

And then the next slicing `[0,0]`:

```
In [39]: idx[mask][0,0]
Out[39]: 6
```

Now we have a single "flat" index back into our original array. We could convert this to a full index by using `np.unravel_index`:

```
In [40]: np.unravel_index(6, arr.shape)
Out[40]: (1, 0)
```

...But it's easier to work directly with `arr.flat` instead:

```
In [41]: arr.flat[6] = 999

In [42]: arr
Out[42]:
array([[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6],
       [999,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16],
       [ 21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26],
       [ 31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36],
       [ 41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46]])
```